# Angular ui-router: load values for data and params from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I want to load `data` and `params` for each state once when the app loads from my service `settings` (this service returns also `promise` since data are loaded asynchronously).
Something like this:

```
  .state('tutorials', {
    url: '/tutorials',
    templateUrl: 'partials/tutorials.html',
    controller: 'TutorialsCtrl',
    data: {details: false},  // instead of false I want: settings.get('tutorials_data_details')
    params: {popular: '512'} // instead of '512' I want: settings.get('tutorials_params_popular')
  })
```

Those `params` must be loaded for all states before entering any state since they are used to build links with `ui-sref` directive that can be placed in any `html` pointing to any state (and those default `params` will be used).

Problem is that I cannot inject `service` into the `config` function. And using `resolve` will not handle all states at once.

I think `$stateProvider.decorator` could be used but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented, but not enough reputation for that.

If it's possible, one option is to create a parent **abstract** state such as `app`, so your state tree would become `app.tutorials` and then you can use `resolve` on the `app` state, allowing all sub-states to use the data/params.

something like this:

```
.state('app', {
url: '',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'partials/tutorials.html',
controller: 'AppCtrl',
resolve: { <resolve your dependencies here> }
})

.state('app.tutorials', {
    url: '/tutorials',
    templateUrl: 'partials/tutorials.html',
    controller: 'TutorialsCtrl'
})
```

Note the Tutorials state wont load until the resolve is completed.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and thinking I came up with these 3 possible solutions:

**1)** By using `decorator` we make all states resolving `settings` service.

```
.decorator('data', function(state, parent) {
  state.resolve.SettingsLoaded = ['settings', function(settings) { return settings.$promise; }];
  return parent(state);
})
```

Then in `settings` service use load success callback to setup states. You can use `$state.get()` to get all states (or with `string` parameter to get specific state by name) and modify the `params` object.
**NOTE** that you cannot use short version like `state.params.popular = '512'` but the full one: `state.params.popular.value = '512'`.

**2)** Those `params` could be actually functions that will be injected and invoked, and the result value will be used.
So the new `params` definition in the `state` will be:

```
params: {popular: ['settings', function(settings) { return settings.get('tutorials_params_popular') || '512'; }]}
```

Also I used again the same `decorator` to make sure `settings` will be resolved before any state is loaded.
I like this approach the most since all parameter values stays in `settings` service and the change is being dynamically reflected.

**3)** Since I'm using `RequireJS`, I could load settings using that and then inject it to the router file. This would however require more changes to the exising code in my `settings` service...